# I don't know how to fetch serialized data in php

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery

My html form is:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post" >
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME" autofocus><br>
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME"><br>
    <input id="gender" name="gender" type="text" placeholder="GENDER" ><br>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL"><br>
    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" placeholder="JOINING DATE" ><br>
    <input id="designation" name="designation" type="text" placeholder="DESIGNATION"><br>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="USER NAME" ><br>
    <input id="password1" name="password1" type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" ><br>
    <input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="CONFORM PASSWORD" ><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

In this program, i'm using ajax for validation. For that i'm serializing the form.

```
data:$("#myform").serialize(),
```

and i don't know how to deserialize it in PHP. Can any one explain the code  to deserialize in PHP, and i used html5 for writing the form.

Comment: just use $_POST in php,you can view array by print_r($_POST)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything, really.

Comment: Y tried it ..but it is not working

Comment: or if you want the variables named as $firstname, $lastname just use extract($_POST) and don't forget to escape/validate the received data on the server side

Comment: alert response data to check that

Comment: **you mean [unserialize**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) ??

Answer (score 0):

As your method is `post`, your variables should be read as any other post variable:

```
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
```

Comment: how can i take date and email like this

Comment: it works the same with any variable, so `$_POST['email']`. If it's not working you should check if you are posting the variables correctly to your php script! Firebug helps with that

Answer (score 0):

use `unserialize()` php function.

`unserialize()` takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

but in your case.. since you are posting the data, you can just take the postd data with there coressponding name..

```
 $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

All serialize do is turn the form fields into a url string that can be sent to a server.

You act on it the same way you act on regular form submitted:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in submitting your form. Check [jquerypost](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) if you are posting by AJAX. or else TRY

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

I had no issues accessing as `$_POST['firstname']` once it got posted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing us the full $.ajax request code: it may be either GET or POST request.

From [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

> By default, Ajax requests are sent using the GET HTTP method. If the
>   POST method is required, the method can be specified by setting a
>   value for the type option.

So in case of GET request you should inspect $_GET in your PHP code. Or just inspect $_REQUEST array. And access the form values as shown in other answers: $_GET["firstname"], for example

Answer (score 0):

The data is retrieved from `$_POST` variable and don't need to be unserialized...
Because Serialized data has been unserialized as array while you send the ajax request